# ¿Cómo probar clases y metodos en php con postman?

Tags: php, json, api, post, postman

Estoy buscando acceder a clases y métodos de un archivo llamado mensaje.php que contiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php

class saludo{
    function dia () {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hola, buenos dias '.$_POST['mensaje']
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    
    function tarde () {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hola, buenas tardes '.$_POST['mensaje']
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    
    function noche () {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hola, buenas noches '.$_POST['mensaje']
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}


class despedida{
    function dia () {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hasta luego '.$_POST['mensaje']. 'buen dia'
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    
    function tarde () {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hasta luego '.$_POST['mensaje']. 'buena tarde'
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    
    function noche () {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hasta luego '.$_POST['mensaje']. 'buenas noches'
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}

?>
```

Quiero acceder a las clases saludo y despedida para mandar a traer los métodos dia, tarde y noche; esto a través del uso de la url:

localhost/api/mensaje.php/nombre de la clase/nombre de la función

ejemplo: localhost/api/mensaje.php/saludo/dia

Estoy haciendo las pruebas con Postman mediante el método POST de la siguiente manera:
[image: Pruebas con postam sin creacion de objetos en php]

Sin embargo no me arroja nada.

Si creo un objeto y mandao a traer sus métodos directamente en php con el siguiente código:

```
<?php

$urlParams = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$className = $urlParams[3];
$functionName = $urlParams[4];

$class= new $className($urlParams);
$class->$functionName($urlParams);

class saludo{
    function dia ($urlParams) {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hola, buenos dias '.$_POST['mensaje']
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    
    function tarde ($urlParams) {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hola, buenas tardes '.$_POST['mensaje']
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    
    function noche ($urlParams) {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hola, buenas noches '.$_POST['mensaje']
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}

class despedida{
    function dia ($urlParams) {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hasta luego '.$_POST['mensaje']. 'buen dia'
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    
    function tarde ($urlParams) {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hasta luego '.$_POST['mensaje']. 'buena tarde'
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    
    function noche ($urlParams) {
        $array = array(
            'Mensaje' => 'Hasta luego'.$_POST['mensaje']. 'buenas noches'
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}

?>
```

Esto me genera algo parecido a lo que busco.

[image: Prueba con postman creando objetos en php]

Sin embargo lo que necesito llamar métodos de la clase sin la creación de objetos directamente en php, sino más bien mediante postman, esto porque en la empresa donde estoy realizando mis prácticas así me lo solicitan.
He buscado información que se relacione con este tema sin poder encontrar algo parecido así que no sé si realmente sea posible realizar algo así, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problema solucionado.
Primero que nada me faltaba el archivo .htaccess

Depende de la ruta utilizada se puede cambiar la posición del arreglo `$url[2]` para el nombre de la clase y `$url[3]` para el nombre del método. Por ejemplo en `localhost/api/saludo/dia` hice uso de lo siguiente:

```
$clase=$url[2];
$metodo=$url[3];
$data = $clase::$metodo();
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.